# Crashing Application

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have 2 viewcontrollers. One contain button  from which I am sending request to server and in another viewcontroller I am displaying data in tableview. Now my application crashed sometimes not everytime when it is executing tableview method. I  got crashed at method CFRetain Here is my log.

Here is my code of tableview:

```
#import "SearchResultViewController.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "SearchResultCell.h"

@interface SearchResultViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchResultViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UIBarButtonItem *btnHelp = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Help" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnHelpAction:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=btnHelp;
self.title = @"Search Result";
}


-(IBAction)btnHelpAction:(id)sender{
HelpViewController *HVC=[[HelpViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *helpNavController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:HVC];
[self presentViewController:helpNavController animated:YES completion:nil];}

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title {
//    [super setTitle:title];
UILabel *titleView = (UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView;
if (!titleView) {
    titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:16.0];
    titleView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241/255.0 green:90/255.0 blue:41/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
}
titleView.text = title;
[titleView sizeToFit];
  }


  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray count];
 // return 1;
 }
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 1;    //changes
 }
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 100;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

SearchResultCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultCell"];
NSArray *tempSearchArray=[MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObject;
    topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchResultCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObject objectAtIndex:0];
}
NSLog(@"%@",[tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:0]);
cell.lblUsername.text = [tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:0];
cell.lblNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:1]];
if([tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:2]==[NSNull null])
{
    NSLog(@"nullll");
    cell.lblFirst_name.text=@"";
}
else{
    cell.lblFirst_name.text = [tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:2];
}
cell.lblLast_name.text = [tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:3];

cell.lblEstablishment.text = @"E1123522";

if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserLogedInType"] intValue] == LoginTypeFacebook) {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBUserLogedInProfileData"] != [NSNull null]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *FBUserProfileData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBUserLogedInProfileData"]];
        [cell.imgIcon setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=100&height=100",[FBUserProfileData objectForKey:@"id"]]]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
    }
}
else {
    if([[tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:6] boolValue]==1){
        ASIFormDataRequest *_requestImage = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLGetImage]];
        __unsafe_unretained ASIFormDataRequest *requestImage = _requestImage;
        [requestImage setPostValue:[tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:4] forKey:@"user_id"];
        [requestImage startAsynchronous];
        [requestImage setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"proimage%@",[requestImage responseData]);
            cell.imgIcon.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[requestImage responseData] scale:1.0f];
        }];
    }
    else{
    [cell.imgIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"No_image.png"]];
    }
}

cell.imgIcon.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
cell.imgIcon.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


DYRateView *rateView = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 75, 120, 20)
                                    fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge.png"]
                                   emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge.png"]];
rateView.padding = 2;
rateView.rate =[[tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:5] floatValue];
//NSLog(@"rating value%f",[[tempSearchArray objectAtIndex:4] floatValue]);
rateView.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
rateView.editable = YES;
rateView.delegate = self;
rateView.editable = NO;
[cell addSubview:rateView];

return cell;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
SearchedProfileViewController *profileVC=[[SearchedProfileViewController alloc]init];
profileVC.cellId=indexPath.section;
NSLog(@"%d",profileVC.cellId);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:profileVC animated:YES];
//[self presentViewController:profileVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

 - (void)rateView:(DYRateView *)rateView changedToNewRate:(NSNumber *)rate {
//    self.rateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

updated crash log:

> ```
> Objective: {objective 0xda869f0: <1:568> + <1:0.5>*0xd982420.marker{id: 726} + <1:-0.5>*_UIParallaxDimmingView:0x1186bb10.Height{id: 707}}
>   2013-12-05 14:41:01.318 GratZeez[1567:3503] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<NSISEngine: 0xc67f090>{ Rows:
> 0xc67fa30.negError{id: 631} == 6 + -1*0xc67d5e0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 495} + 1*0xc67fa30.posErrorMarker{id: 630}
> 0xc685ce0.posErrorMarker{id: 644} == 132 + 1*0xc68b900:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 509} + 1*0xc685ce0.negError{id: 645}
> 0xc6888b0.posErrorMarker{id: 658} == 106 + 1*0xc68b9c0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 517} + 1*0xc6888b0.negError{id: 659}
> 0xc6888f0.posErrorMarker{id: 660} == 0 + 1*0xc67b5d0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 519} + 1*0xc6888f0.negError{id: 661}
> 0xc69ffd0.posErrorMarker{id: 646} == 0 + 1*0xc68b930:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 511} + 1*0xc69ffd0.negError{id: 647}
> 0xc6b3200.posErrorMarker{id: 628} == 90 + 1*0xc67ace0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 493} + 1*0xc6b3200.negError{id: 629}
> 0xc6b45d0.posErrorMarker{id: 636} == 114 + 1*0xc67d670:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 501} + 1*0xc6b45d0.negError{id: 637}
> 0xc6b4620.posErrorMarker{id: 638} == 0 + 1*0xc67d6a0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 503} + 1*0xc6b4620.negError{id: 639}
> 0xc6b4dc0.posErrorMarker{id: 664} == 72 + 1*0xc67b660:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 525} + 1*0xc6b4dc0.negError{id: 665}
> 0xc6b4e00.posErrorMarker{id: 667} == 0 + 1*0xc67b690:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 527} + 1*0xc6b4e00.negError{id: 668}
> 0xd9707e0.posErrorMarker{id: 589} == 128 + 1*0xc6b34d0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 553} + 1*0xd9707e0.negError{id: 590}
> 0xd970820.posErrorMarker{id: 591} == 0 + 1*0xc6b3500:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 555} + 1*0xd970820.negError{id: 592}
> 0xd974070.posErrorMarker{id: 585} == 104 + 1*0xc6b3410:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 545} + 1*0xd974070.negError{id: 586}
> 0xd977ca0.posErrorMarker{id: 632} == 90 + 1*0xc6b3650:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 569} + 1*0xd977ca0.negError{id: 633}
> 0xd977dd0.posErrorMarker{id: 634} == 0 + 1*0xc6b3680:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 571} + 1*0xd977dd0.negError{id: 635}
> 0xd97a6d0.negError{id: 588} == 6 + -1*0xc6b3440:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 547} + 1*0xd97a6d0.posErrorMarker{id: 587}
> 0xd97ac70.posErrorMarker{id: 640} == 72 + 1*0xc6b3710:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 577} + 1*0xd97ac70.negError{id: 641}
> 0xd97acd0.posErrorMarker{id: 642} == 0 + 1*0xc6b3740:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 579} + 1*0xd97acd0.negError{id: 643}
> 0xd97cfb0.posErrorMarker{id: 601} == 200 + 1*0xc6b3590:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 561} + 1*0xd97cfb0.negError{id: 602}
> 0xd97cff0.posErrorMarker{id: 603} == 42 + 1*0xc6b35c0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 563} + 1*0xd97cff0.negError{id: 604}
> SearchResultCell:0xc6ade20.Height{id: 652} == 200 + 1*0xd97b820.marker{id: 655}
> SearchResultCell:0xc6ade20.Width{id: 650} == 640 + 2*0xd97b7c0.marker{id: 653} + 1*0xd97bd90.marker{id: 670}
> SearchResultCell:0xc6ade20.minX{id: 649} == 0 + 2*0xd97b790.marker{id: 648} + -1*0xd97b7c0.marker{id: 653}
> SearchResultCell:0xc6ade20.minY{id: 651} == 0 + 2*0xd97b7f0.marker{id: 654} + -0.5*0xd97b820.marker{id: 655}
> SearchResultCell:0xc6b2fd0.Height{id: 617} == 200 + 1*0xc6a6a20.marker{id: 625}
> SearchResultCell:0xc6b2fd0.Width{id: 614} == 640 + 2*0xc672a00.marker{id: 623} + 1*0xd97bd90.marker{id: 670}
> SearchResultCell:0xc6b2fd0.minX{id: 620} == 0 + 2*0xc6a03a0.marker{id: 619} + -1*0xc672a00.marker{id: 623}
> SearchResultCell:0xc6b2fd0.minY{id: 621} == 200 + 2*0xc673060.marker{id: 624} + -0.5*0xc6a6a20.marker{id: 625}
> UIImageView:0xc67faa0.Height{id: 540} == 150 + 1*0xc6b3380:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 539}
> UIImageView:0xc67faa0.Width{id: 538} == 150 + 1*0xc6b3350:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 537}
> UIImageView:0xc67faa0.minX{id: 534} == 20 + 1*0xc6b32a0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 533}
> UIImageView:0xc67faa0.minY{id: 536} == 24 + 1*0xc6b3320:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 535}
> UIImageView:0xc696c80.Height{id: 488} == 150 + 1*0xc67ac50:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 487}
> UIImageView:0xc696c80.Width{id: 486} == 150 + 1*0xc67ac20:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 485}
> UIImageView:0xc696c80.minX{id: 482} == 20 + 1*0xc699a30:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 481}
> UIImageView:0xc696c80.minY{id: 484} == 24 + 1*0xc699ab0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 483}
> UILabel:0xc6732d0.Height{id: 548} == 42 + 1*0xc6b3440:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 547}
> UILabel:0xc6732d0.Width{id: 546} == 434 + 1*0xc6b3410:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 545}
> UILabel:0xc6732d0.minX{id: 542} == 186 + 1*0xc6b33b0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 541}
> UILabel:0xc6732d0.minY{id: 544} == 20 + 1*0xc6b33e0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 543}
> UILabel:0xc67bf90.Height{id: 564} == 42 + 1*0xc6b35c0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 563}
> UILabel:0xc67bf90.Width{id: 562} == 200 + 1*0xc6b3590:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 561}
> UILabel:0xc67bf90.minX{id: 558} == 420 + 1*0xc6b3530:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 557}
> UILabel:0xc67bf90.minY{id: 560} == 68 + 1*0xc6b3560:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 559}
> UILabel:0xc67d490.Height{id: 572} == 42 + 1*0xc6b3680:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 571}
> UILabel:0xc67d490.Width{id: 570} == 200 + 1*0xc6b3650:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 569}
> UILabel:0xc67d490.minX{id: 566} == 186 + 1*0xc6b35f0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 565}
> UILabel:0xc67d490.minY{id: 568} == 106 + 1*0xc6b3620:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 567}
> UILabel:0xc67d840.Height{id: 512} == 42 + 1*0xc68b930:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 511}
> UILabel:0xc67d840.Width{id: 510} == 200 + 1*0xc68b900:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 509}
> UILabel:0xc67d840.minX{id: 506} == 420 + 1*0xc67d6d0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 505}
> UILabel:0xc67d840.minY{id: 508} == 68 + 1*0xc68b8d0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 507}
> UILabel:0xc681210.Height{id: 504} == 42 + 1*0xc67d6a0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 503}
> UILabel:0xc681210.Width{id: 502} == 200 + 1*0xc67d670:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 501}
> UILabel:0xc681210.minX{id: 498} == 186 + 1*0xc67d610:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 497}
> UILabel:0xc681210.minY{id: 500} == 68 + 1*0xc67d640:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 499}
> UILabel:0xc683e20.Height{id: 520} == 42 + 1*0xc67b5d0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 519}
> UILabel:0xc683e20.Width{id: 518} == 200 + 1*0xc68b9c0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 517}
> UILabel:0xc683e20.minX{id: 514} == 186 + 1*0xc68b960:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 513}
> UILabel:0xc683e20.minY{id: 516} == 106 + 1*0xc68b990:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 515}
> UILabel:0xc685a40.Height{id: 556} == 42 + 1*0xc6b3500:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 555}
> UILabel:0xc685a40.Width{id: 554} == 200 + 1*0xc6b34d0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 553}
> UILabel:0xc685a40.minX{id: 550} == 186 + 1*0xc6b3470:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 549}
> UILabel:0xc685a40.minY{id: 552} == 68 + 1*0xc6b34a0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 551}
> UILabel:0xc686460.Height{id: 580} == 42 + 1*0xc6b3740:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 579}
> UILabel:0xc686460.Width{id: 578} == 200 + 1*0xc6b3710:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 577}
> UILabel:0xc686460.minX{id: 574} == 420 + 1*0xc6b36b0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 573}
> UILabel:0xc686460.minY{id: 576} == 106 + 1*0xc6b36e0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 575}
> UILabel:0xc68a640.Height{id: 528} == 42 + 1*0xc67b690:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 527}
> UILabel:0xc68a640.Width{id: 526} == 200 + 1*0xc67b660:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 525}
> UILabel:0xc68a640.minX{id: 522} == 420 + 1*0xc67b600:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 521}
> UILabel:0xc68a640.minY{id: 524} == 106 + 1*0xc67b630:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 523}
> UILabel:0xc68c5d0.Height{id: 496} == 42 + 1*0xc67d5e0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 495}
> UILabel:0xc68c5d0.Width{id: 494} == 434 + 1*0xc67ace0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 493}
> UILabel:0xc68c5d0.minX{id: 490} == 186 + 1*0xc67ac80:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 489}
> UILabel:0xc68c5d0.minY{id: 492} == 20 + 1*0xc67acb0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 491}
> UILayoutContainerView:0xc670770.Height{id: 393} == 1136 + 1*0xc685240:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height.marker{id: 398}
> UILayoutContainerView:0xc670770.Width{id: 390} == 640 + 1*0xc685210:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width.marker{id: 395}
> UINavigationTransitionView:0xc6720e0.Height{id: 389} == 1136 + 2*0xc6844d0.marker{id: 394} + 1*0xc685240:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height.marker{id: 398}
> UINavigationTransitionView:0xc6720e0.Width{id: 387} == 640 + 2*0xc684430.marker{id: 391} + 1*0xc685210:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width.marker{id: 395}
> UINavigationTransitionView:0xc6720e0.minX{id: 386} == 0 + 2*0xc684400.marker{id: 385} + -1*0xc684430.marker{id: 391}
> UINavigationTransitionView:0xc6720e0.minY{id: 388} == 0 + 2*0xc6844a0.marker{id: 392} + -1*0xc6844d0.marker{id: 394}
> UITableView:0x14a40a00.Height{id: 701} == 0 + 1*_UIParallaxDimmingView:0x1186bb10.Height{id: 707} + 2*0xd97c220.marker{id: 710}
> UITableView:0x14a40a00.Width{id: 699} == 640 + 2*0xd97c1c0.marker{id: 703} + 1*0xd9823c0.marker{id: 719} + -2*tempToBeOptimizedToZero{id: 720}
> UITableView:0x14a40a00.contentHeight{id: 480} == 400 + 1*0xc6ad9c0.marker{id: 479}
> UITableView:0x14a40a00.contentWidth{id: 478} == 640 + 1*0xc6ad980.marker{id: 477}
> UITableView:0x14a40a00.minX{id: 698} == 0 + 2*0xd97c190.marker{id: 697} + -1*0xd97c1c0.marker{id: 703}
> UITableView:0x14a40a00.minY{id: 700} == 0 + 2*0xd97c1f0.marker{id: 705} + -1*0xd97c220.marker{id: 710}
> UITableViewCellContentView:0xc67b900.Height{id: 677} == 199 + 1*0xc6b51c0.marker{id: 683}
> UITableViewCellContentView:0xc67b900.Width{id: 675} == 640 + 1*0xc6b5160.marker{id: 678}
> UITableViewCellContentView:0xc67b900.minX{id: 674} == 0 + 2*0xc6b5130.marker{id: 673} + -0.5*0xc6b5160.marker{id: 678}
> UITableViewCellContentView:0xc67b900.minY{id: 676} == 0 + 2*0xc6b5190.marker{id: 681} + -0.5*0xc6b51c0.marker{id: 683}
> UITableViewCellContentView:0xc6a7d10.Height{id: 597} == 199 + 1*0xc6ae810.marker{id: 606}
> UITableViewCellContentView:0xc6a7d10.Width{id: 595} == 640 + 1*0xc6ae700.marker{id: 598}
> UITableViewCellContentView:0xc6a7d10.minX{id: 594} == 0 + 2*0xc6ae660.marker{id: 593} + -0.5*0xc6ae700.marker{id: 598}
> UITableViewCellContentView:0xc6a7d10.minY{id: 596} == 0 + 2*0xc6ae750.marker{id: 605} + -0.5*0xc6ae810.marker{id: 606}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6aeb60.Height{id: 693} == 200 + 1*0xd97b820.marker{id: 655} + 2*0xc6b5c10.marker{id: 706}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6aeb60.Width{id: 691} == 640 + 2*0xd97b7c0.marker{id: 653} + 1*0xd97bd90.marker{id: 670} + 2*0xc6b5bb0.marker{id: 694}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6aeb60.contentHeight{id: 532} == 200 + 1*0xc68c560.marker{id: 531}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6aeb60.contentWidth{id: 530} == 640 + 1*0xc68c4c0.marker{id: 529}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6aeb60.minX{id: 690} == 0 + 2*0xc6b5d00.marker{id: 689} + -1*0xc6b5bb0.marker{id: 694}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6aeb60.minY{id: 692} == 0 + 2*0xc6b5be0.marker{id: 704} + -1*0xc6b5c10.marker{id: 706}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6b3880.Height{id: 613} == 200 + 2*0xc6b2480.marker{id: 618} + 1*0xc6a6a20.marker{id: 625}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6b3880.Width{id: 611} == 640 + 2*0xc6b22e0.marker{id: 615} + 2*0xc672a00.marker{id: 623} + 1*0xd97bd90.marker{id: 670}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6b3880.contentHeight{id: 584} == 200 + 1*0xc6b3ce0.marker{id: 583}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6b3880.contentWidth{id: 582} == 640 + 1*0xc6b37d0.marker{id: 581}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6b3880.minX{id: 610} == 0 + 2*0xc6b2220.marker{id: 609} + -1*0xc6b22e0.marker{id: 615}
> UITableViewCellScrollView:0xc6b3880.minY{id: 612} == 0 + 2*0xc6b23b0.marker{id: 616} + -1*0xc6b2480.marker{id: 618}
> UITableViewWrapperView:0x1186b2c0.Height{id: 669} == 1136 + 1*0xd97bdf0.marker{id: 686}
> UITableViewWrapperView:0x1186b2c0.Width{id: 622} == 640 + 1*0xd97bd90.marker{id: 670}
> UITableViewWrapperView:0x1186b2c0.minX{id: 663} == 0 + 2*0xd97bd60.marker{id: 662} + -0.5*0xd97bd90.marker{id: 670}
> UITableViewWrapperView:0x1186b2c0.minY{id: 666} == 0 + 2*0xd97bdc0.marker{id: 682} + -0.5*0xd97bdf0.marker{id: 686}
> UIView:0xc674820.Height{id: 453} == 1136 + 1*0xc679f40.marker{id: 474}
> UIView:0xc674820.Width{id: 451} == 640 + 1*0xc69ff70.marker{id: 470}
> UIView:0xc674820.minX{id: 450} == -192 + 2*0xc69ff40.marker{id: 469} + -0.5*0xc69ff70.marker{id: 470}
> UIView:0xc674820.minY{id: 452} == 0 + 2*0xc69ffa0.marker{id: 473} + -0.5*0xc679f40.marker{id: 474}
> UIView:0xc6752d0.Height{id: 718} == 1136 + 1*0xd982620.marker{id: 730}
> UIView:0xc6752d0.Width{id: 716} == 640 + 1*0xd9825c0.marker{id: 722}
> UIView:0xc6752d0.minX{id: 715} == 0 + 2*0xd982580.marker{id: 714} + -0.5*0xd9825c0.marker{id: 722}
> UIView:0xc6752d0.minY{id: 717} == 0 + 2*0xd9825f0.marker{id: 729} + -0.5*0xd982620.marker{id: 730}
> UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc687700.Height{id: 377} == 1136 + 1*0xc683fa0.marker{id: 382}
> UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc687700.Width{id: 375} == 640 + 1*0xc683f00.marker{id: 378}
> UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc687700.minX{id: 374} == 0 + 2*0xc683ed0.marker{id: 373} + -0.5*0xc683f00.marker{id: 378}
> UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc687700.minY{id: 376} == 0 + 2*0xc683f70.marker{id: 381} + -0.5*0xc683fa0.marker{id: 382}
> _UIParallaxDimmingView:0x1186bb10.Width{id: 702} == 640 + 1*0xd9823c0.marker{id: 719}
> _UIParallaxDimmingView:0x1186bb10.minX{id: 712} == 0 + 2*0xd982390.marker{id: 711} + -0.5*0xd9823c0.marker{id: 719} + 1*tempToBeOptimizedToZero{id: 720}
> _UIParallaxDimmingView:0x1186bb10.minY{id: 713} == 568 + -0.5*_UIParallaxDimmingView:0x1186bb10.Height{id: 707} + 2*0xd9823f0.marker{id: 725}
> objective{id: 243} == {objective 0xc67e090: <750:12, 251:1150> + <251:1>*0xc67ace0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 493} + <251:1>*0xc67b5d0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 519} + <251:1>*0xc67b660:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 525} + <251:1>*0xc67b690:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 527} + <750:-1>*0xc67d5e0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 495} + <251:1>*0xc67d670:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 501} + <251:1>*0xc67d6a0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 503} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc67fa30.posErrorMarker{id: 630} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc685ce0.negError{id: 645} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc6888b0.negError{id: 659} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc6888f0.negError{id: 661} + <251:1>*0xc68b900:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 509} + <251:1>*0xc68b930:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 511} + <251:1>*0xc68b9c0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 517} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc69ffd0.negError{id: 647} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc6b3200.negError{id: 629} + <251:1>*0xc6b3410:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 545} + <750:-1>*0xc6b3440:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 547} + <251:1>*0xc6b34d0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 553} + <251:1>*0xc6b3500:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 555} + <251:1>*0xc6b3590:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 561} + <251:1>*0xc6b35c0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 563} + <251:1>*0xc6b3650:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 569} + <251:1>*0xc6b3680:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 571} + <251:1>*0xc6b3710:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 577} + <251:1>*0xc6b3740:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 579} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc6b45d0.negError{id: 637} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc6b4620.negError{id: 639} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc6b4dc0.negError{id: 665} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc6b4e00.negError{id: 668} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd9707e0.negError{id: 590} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd970820.negError{id: 592} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd974070.negError{id: 586} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd977ca0.negError{id: 633} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd977dd0.negError{id: 635} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd97a6d0.posErrorMarker{id: 587} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd97ac70.negError{id: 641} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd97acd0.negError{id: 643} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd97cfb0.negError{id: 602} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xd97cff0.negError{id: 604}}
> tempToBeOptimizedToZeroObjective{id: 728} == {objective 0xda869f0: <1:568> + <1:0.5>*0xd982420.marker{id: 726} + <1:-0.5>*_UIParallaxDimmingView:0x1186bb10.Height{id: 707}}
> tempToBeOptimizedToZero{id: 727} == 568 + -0.5*_UIParallaxDimmingView:0x1186bb10.Height{id: 707} + 0.5*0xd982420.marker{id: 726}
> ```

```
     Constraints:
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc672a00 h=-&- v=--& SearchResultCell:0xc6b2fd0.width == UITableViewWrapperView:0x1186b2c0.width>      Marker:0xc672a00.marker{id: 623}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc673060 h=-&- v=--& SearchResultCell:0xc6b2fd0.midY == + 150>     Marker:0xc673060.marker{id: 624}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc679f40 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0xc674820(568)]>        Marker:0xc679f40.marker{id: 474}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc683ed0 h=--& v=--& UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc687700.midX == + 160>      Marker:0xc683ed0.marker{id: 373}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc683f00 h=--& v=--& H:[UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc687700(320)]>       Marker:0xc683f00.marker{id: 378}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc683f70 h=--& v=--& UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc687700.midY == + 284>      Marker:0xc683f70.marker{id: 381}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc683fa0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc687700(568)]>       Marker:0xc683fa0.marker{id: 382}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc684400 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0xc6720e0.midX == UILayoutContainerView:0xc670770.midX>        Marker:0xc684400.marker{id: 385}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc684430 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0xc6720e0.width == UILayoutContainerView:0xc670770.width>      Marker:0xc684430.marker{id: 391}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc6844a0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0xc6720e0.midY == UILayoutContainerView:0xc670770.midY>        Marker:0xc6844a0.marker{id: 392}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc6844d0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0xc6720e0.height == UILayoutContainerView:0xc670770.height>        Marker:0xc6844d0.marker{id: 394}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc69ff40 h=--& v=--& UIView:0xc674820.midX == + 64>        Marker:0xc69ff40.marker{id: 469}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc69ff70 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0xc674820(320)]>        Marker:0xc69ff70.marker{id: 470}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc69ffa0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0xc674820.midY == + 284>       Marker:0xc69ffa0.marker{id: 473}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc6a03a0 h=-&- v=--& SearchResultCell:0xc6b2fd0.midX == UITableViewWrapperView:0x1186b2c0.midX>        Marker:0xc6a03a0.marker{id: 619}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc6a6a20 h=-&- v=--& V:[SearchResultCell:0xc6b2fd0(100)]>      Marker:0xc6a6a20.marker{id: 625}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc6ae660 h=--& v=--& UITableViewCellContentView:0xc6a7d10.midX == + 160>       Marker:0xc6ae660.marker{id: 593}
```

and many more log about autoresizing and contentsize

Comment: About NSAutoLayout should be in another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means your mutable NSSet is changed while enumerating.

OK, After checking your code, you have unsafe code. You are using MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray as datasource of your table. That is the point sometimes causing you crash.

Just think about what if MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray is changed while UITableView is loading?

You should make sure your data source should be static while loading table view. Better set it on the same class which is your ViewController.

Comment: can you explain me...more...I have not used NSSet in mu code.

Comment: Have you used collection data type? like NSMutableArray or NSMuableSet? When you enumerating those collection data, you should not change it while enumerating. You say you don't use NSSet at all in your code but is there any methods return NSSet? Because your crash log is very obvious saying about that.

Comment: sorry i didnt receive any notification...i got your point...i will check my code tomorrow and try to do something that you have  suggested...and if i will have any doubt then i will ask you...thank you friend for your help

Comment: 1. Did you change your datasource? 2. NSAutoLayout is different topic so you can post it another thread.

Comment: but how to change my datasource...When i request to server for related data it will response me that data and i want to display that data to tableview. I pushed tableviewcontroller in completion block of request and after i fetched response and set myappdelegate.searchresult.

Comment: what i have modified after your suggestion is that...I have create another array and passed myappdelegate.searchresult value to it in viewdidload before tablemethod call. Because i think after viewdidload tbale datasource method will only called...is this ok?? because when i have made this change i didnt receive any crash related to "NSSet mutable changed."

Comment: Yes, that should be OK for this question. Because you have another instance array for datasource. In this case, even myappdelegate.searchresult changed it won't change new instance.

Comment: yes...i also think that this should work...and now for autoresizing can you suggest me something???

Comment: mmm, I need more details about Auto layout. Can you please accept my answer here as I do solve your question and post new thread about auto layout? I will have a look at what is going on there soon.

Comment: at this time it is not giving me any crash so i am accepting your answer...and i hope in future this also work fine

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with NSLayoutConstraint and multiplier in ios 7, ios 8 work perfect.

I m using multipler whit value 0.2 and cause errors!! Alter value multipler for 1 and get size screen in constant value to nslayoutconstraint.

NSLayoutConstraint(item: BT_Facebook, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.2 , constant: sizeBtRedeSociais)

```
Solution is usage size of screen, and not percent.
var sizeBtRedeSociais = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 5
var BT_FacebookWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: BT_Facebook, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: sizeBtRedeSociais)
    var BT_TwitterWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: BT_Twitter, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: sizeBtRedeSociais)
    var BT_InstagramWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: BT_Instagram, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: sizeBtRedeSociais)
    var BT_GoogleWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: BT_Google, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: sizeBtRedeSociais)
    var BT_YoutubeWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: BT_Youtube, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: sizeBtRedeSociais)
```